# ImportError: No module named rc.manager when installing dataplicity on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I'm trying to install dataplicity in my Raspberry Pi, in order to perform a little home made project of domotics.

Can you help me?

There are two kinds of errors while installation process:

**First:**

```
ImportError: cannot import name develop
```

**Second:**

```
ImportError: No module named rc.manager
```

**In order to help you to understand what's going on, I'm posting the coding that cointains the errors:**

```
[....] Starting dataplicity...: dataplicityTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dataplicity", line 2, in <module>
from dataplicity.app import App

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataplicity/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from dataplicity.app.app import App

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataplicity/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
from dataplicity.client import Client

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataplicity/client/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .client import Client

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataplicity/client/client.py", line 7, in <module>
from dataplicity.rc.manager import RCManager

ImportError: No module named rc.manager
```

Comment: Can you post the command that creates the error?

Comment: This is what I type in order to download and install the app:

`code sudo bash -c "$(curl -sL https://developer.dataplicity.com/rpi.sh)" df64a2d409074de3`

Comment: Do you know about https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/? This does not seem like an SO question to me.

Comment: I'm here because I'm asking what can I do? Which module do I need to install...

Answer (score 0):

This bug has now been fixed in dataplicity v 0.3.9.1.  You can update by using:

pip install -U dataplicity

Or running the auto installer again.